# Is there an easy way to remove specific chars from a char*?

Tags: c

```
char * deleteChars = "\"\'.“”‘’?:;-,—*($%)! \t\n\x0A\r"
```

I have this and i'm trying to remove any of these from a given char*. I'm not sure how I would go about comparing a char* to it.

For example if the char* is equal to "hello," how would I go about removing that comma with my deleteChars?

So far I have

```
void removeChar(char*p, char*delim){
char*holder = p;
while(*p){
    if(!(*p==*delim++)){
        *holder++=*p;
        p++;
    }
}
*holder = '\0';
```

Comment: Any number of ways are possible. What have you tried ?

Comment: You won't be able to modify the string pointed at by `deleteChars` (or any other string literal).  String literals cannot be modified reliably, and your code will usually crash if you try to do so.  It is easy enough to arrange to copy a source string into a modifiable target string omitting any characters listed above.  How many ways are there of searching through that string for a character?  `strchr()` is one such.  You can also use methods that use more storage but reduce the search time.  Be wary of signed characters.

Comment: Edited with what I have so far.

Also I'm not trying to edit deleteChars. Those are the chars I want to delete from a random string p.

Comment: You could use `strspn()` and `strcspn()` Plus maybe `memmove()`.

Comment: regarding: `if(!(*p==*delim++)){`  this changes where `delim` points so will fail if any of the characters in `p` are not in the same order as in `delim` and/or a `delim` character is encountered more than once

Answer (score 2):

A simple one-by-one approach:

You can use `strchr` to decide if the character is present in the deletion set. You then assign back into the buffer at the next unassigned position, only if not a filtered character.

It might be easier to understand this using two indices, instead of using pointer arithmetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove_characters(char *from, const char *set)
{
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    while (from[i]) {
        if (!strchr(set, from[i]))
            from[j++] = from[i];
        i++;
    }

    from[j] = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    const char *del = "\"\'.“”‘’?:;-,—*($%)! \t\n\x0A\r";
    char buf[] = "hello, world!";

    remove_characters(buf, del);

    puts(buf);
}
```

`stdout`:

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've several delimiters/characters to ignore, it's better to use a look-up table.

```c
void remove_chars (char* str, const char* delims)
{
    if (!str || !delims) return;

    char* ans = str;
    int dlt[256] = {0};
    while (*delims)
        dlt[(unsigned char)*delims++] = 1;

    while (*str) {
        if (dlt[(unsigned char)*str])
            ++str; // skip it
        else //if (str != ans)
            *ans++ = *str++;
    }
    *ans = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for `int dlt[]` vs. the quarter size `char dlt[]`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a double loop, but depending on what you want to treat, it might not be ideal. And since you are FOR SURE shrinking the string you don't need to malloc (provided it was already malloced). I'd initialize a table like this.

```
#include <string.h>
...
char del[256];
memset(del, 0, 256 * sizeof(char));
for (int i = 0; deleteChars[i]; i++) del[deleteChars[i]] = 1;
```

Then in a function:

```
void delChars(char *del, char *string) {
  int i, offset;
  for (i = 0, offset = 0; string[i]; i++) {
    string[i - offset] = string[i];
    if (del[string[i]]) offset++;
  }
  string[i - offset] = 0;
}
```

This will not work on string literals (that you initialize with `char* x = ""`) though because you'd end up writing in program memory, and probably segfault. I'm sure you can tweak it if that's your need. (Just do something like `char *newString = malloc(strlen(string) + 1); newString[i - offset] = string[i]`)

Comment: Note that `size_t i, offset;` handles all strings whereas `int i, offset;` would fail on _long_ strings.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `strchr(delim, p[i])` to each element in `p[]`.

Let us take advantage that `strchr(delim, 0)` always returns a non-`NULL` pointer to eliminate the the *null character* test for every interrelation.

```
void removeChar(char *p, char *delim) {
  size_t out = 0;
  for (size_t in; /* empty */; in++) {
    // p[in] in the delim set?
    if (strchr(delim, p[in])) {
      if (p[in] == '\0') {
        break;
      }
    } else {
      p[out++] = p[in];
    }
  }
  p[out] = '\0';
}
```

Variation on [@Oka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71417460/2410359) good answer.

Answer (score -1):

it is better way - return the string without needless characters

```
#include <string.h>
char * remove_chars(char * str, const char * delim) {
    for ( char * p = strpbrk(str, delim); p; p = strpbrk(p, delim) )
        memmove(p, p + 1, strlen(p));
    return str;
}
```

Comment: That can lead to quadratic running time if there are many characters to be deleted in the source string.

Comment: regarding: `memmove(p, p + 1, strlen(p));`  THis will result in characters sourced from beyond the end of the string pointed to by `p`.  Resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you seriously? How does a string usually end in C and what is not taken into account by the function strlen()?